# Python: How to resolve TypeError issue from Try Except function?

Tags: python

I'm a python newbie and I'd like to understand how I can avoid getting TypeError error from my Try and Except function with zeros.

Given:

```
a= 0 (usually I have a number (>=1), but I could get 0 as an input)
b= 0 (usually I have a number (>=1), but I could get 0 as an input)
```

Here is the code:

```
try:
  h = a/b
except ZeroDivisionError:
  h = 0
```

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Comment: Can you share minimal code to reproduce your error? Copying and pasting your code and running with python 3.11 doesn't reproduce it. You can also look at this informative post for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123418/catching-classes-that-do-not-inherit-from-baseexception-is-not-allowed

Comment: The only possible way this could happen is if you defined your own custom `ZeroDivisionError` class, replacing the built-in one.  Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your custom exception `ZeroDivisionError` must inherit from the `BaseException` class.

```
class MyZeroDivisionError(Exception):
    pass
```

That said, this error ships with base Python. In fact, your snippet works for me, and I am unable to reproduce the `TypeError`. Can you either share a reproducible example, or the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created a `class ZeroDivisionError` that does **not** inherit from `Exception`, thus the error.

In case of a built in exception (docs: [click me](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)), it's better that you just use that.

```py
>>> try:
...   5/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...   print("Cannot divide by zero!")
...
Cannot divide by zero!
```

---

EDIT: to create a custom class that can be caught by your program you can do something like:

```py
>>> class MyException(Exception):
...   pass
...
>>> try:
...   raise MyException("My error message")
... except MyException as e:
...   print(e)
...
My error message
```